# Using query arguments with operators for collections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api, graphql

In GraphQL how does one best design an "API query language" to filter collections of items **with operators**?

For example in REST you can have parameters such as

`/family/people?height="192"&weight[]=">=65"&weight[]="<=100"`

In GraphQL it seems to go against best practice to implment query logic outside of the GraphQL layer as such:

```
{
    family {
        people(height: 192, weight: ['>=65','<=100']) {
            givenName
            surName
            age
        }
    }
}
```

Although it seems overly verbose and not very DRY to do the following:

```
{
    family {
        people(height: 192, weightGte: '65', weightLte: '100') {
            givenName
            surName
            age
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a convention for query arguments that have operators such as `>  <  >=  <=  == != *` ?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's a graphQL issue per se, but rather - the approach you'll choose to utilize onto your solution.

Assuming we're talking JS (considering your tags), I'd go with wrapping your query with a function, similar to:

```
function getPeople(height, weight) {
  let [0: weightGte, 1: weightLte ] = weight;
  return {
    family {
        people(height, weightGte, weightLte) {
            givenName
            surName
            age
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Depending on your flavour of js and the way you create your query document, you can simply call it with different arguments.

If you're reusing the same arguments, then you can cache the document and use the cached version instead:

```
const commonUseCase = getPeople(192, [65, 100]);

//elsewhere in your code

query(commonCase).then(...
```